# GnuCash v5.4 - (GNOME Dark Mode only) after the description text is highlighted, the actual text blurs (Cannot read it clearly)

Tags: colors, gnome, manjaro, dark-mode, gnucash

For example, In the **General Journal view**, when I select a text in the description,  I cannot the read it clearly.

(trying to copy manually, though i know, GnuCash autofills the description when creating a new line by typing few letters)

> This issue occurs only when using **OS: Manjaro, GNOME & Dark Mode**

Same is the case, if I select Date, amount or any other column. It happens everywhere (not just General Journal)

Can you please suggest, on how to fix this issue?

**Screenshot:**
In the Screenshot, I cannot read the text after the text is highlighted (the actual text is Amazon)[image]

Comment: This might be helpful : [Text in GTK 4 applications is blurry or renders incorrectly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK#Text_in_GTK_4_applications_is_blurry_or_renders_incorrectly).